# If I create views programmatically and add them to the view hierarchy, why do they need to be strong references?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a simple view controller with several view objects in it that I've created programatically. Here is part of ViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView* scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* listingTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView* listingMap;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* listingPrice;
```

As you can see, they are all strong references. If I make any of them weak references, ARC deallocates them. It was to my understanding that if they are added to the view hierarchy, they do not deallocate, as they are owned by the next level view in the hierarchy. For one of them, as an example, I did so here:

```
self.listingTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 10, 60)];
[self.scrollView addSubview:listingTitle];
```

But again, it deallocates if I give it a weak reference. Why is that?

Comment: Im assuming its because ARC deallocates it BEFORE adding it to the hierarchy? how can i get around this if its the case.

Comment: Why do you want the property to be weak?

Comment: Weak references are relatively uncommon. There are good reasons why they're not the default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is because you create the subviews and immediately assign there references to weak properties. As a result the subviews are deallocated immediately, before they are added to the superview. If you want to have weak properties you may do something like this:

```
UIView *mySubview = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 10, 60)];
[self.scrollView addSubview: mySubview];
self.listingTitle = mySubview;
```

Comment: would this be better than what I am currently using? if so, why? in terms of memory management of course.

Comment: With ARC and in modern versions of iOS I do not see much difference. With manual management you would need to release the references in dealloc if you use strong property.

Comment: @yurish However, the resulting code would be more fragile than would be the case if the properties were qualified as `strong`.

Comment: @jlehr could you elaborate what you mean. I don't see how making properties weak makes things worse. In fact weak properties are default if you create subview outlets in Interface Builder and weak properties for subviews were used with manual reference counting to avoid releasing them in dealloc (and also in low memory conditions in old iOS versions if I'm not mistaken). The only pitfall I know is the one encountered by the OP.

Comment: I'm referring to the problem the OP posted. Note that his properties are not declared with `IBOutlet`, so clearly his intent wasn't to hook them up in IB. Your solution is to create a strong local reference before adding to the subviews array and only then setting the property. That's slightly more complex and more fragile than simply setting a strong property with the new instance IMO.

Answer (score -1):

Views do keep a strong reference to their sub views, so there must be something else going on that is causing the views to get dealloc'd.

Comment: The OP's code is storing a reference to a newly created view in a `weak` property initially, so by the time he tries to add it to the `subviews` array it's already  deallocated itself.